# Changing radiators to radiant wall heating

Tags: radiator, radiant-heating

In my bedroom/study I have only a radiator as heating. The problem is that the water flow is controlled by the thermostat in the living. This means that around wintertime my room has a big change in temperature. It is hard to control the heating of my room and because I use my bedroom also as a study I spend a lot of time in it. The problem is that once the temperature in the living in 20°c the thermostat stop the heating of the radiators and so it stops the heating of my room. That way sometimes my room only achieve a poor 14°C which is not comfortable to use as a study. But If I turn up the radiator in my room higher, there is a chance (it only happens a few times) that it reaches 21-22°C which is to hot for me to sleep.

I thought about a solution: if I changed the radiator (most of it is just heating air in stead of giving radiant heat) into a radiant heating system, it could solve my problem. I was thinking about a system like a 'heat wall', that's where they placed heated water lines against the wall and then place cob over it. But that system is designed for low temperature heating systems, in which the water is far less hot than it is when used for radiators. But I think that if I make like an extra cob wall of like 20 cm thick, I could store some of that hot water heat for when the thermostats stops the hot water circulation. That way the hot water used for the radiator would not result in an extreme hot wall surface, but it would result in a buffering radiant heating wall.

I was wondering if this idea can work or if there will be major issues. My idea for the moment is: replace the radiator by a water pipe network and then put cob around it. Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Are your radiators steam or hot water?

Comment: Do you mean "Cob" as in earth, wood fiber and whatnot? Is this a cottage? I'm not familiar with this term, but may have advise depending on what this is.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the delivery method in the room does not address the (evident) actual problem of having the space controlled by a thermostat in a different room which does not track well with it.

Radiant wall can be a nice setup, but it is also very slow to respond, so you will probably make the disconnect between the living room thermostat and the bedroom worse, not better.

Unless you have a major desire to try radiant wall, simply splitting the heating into more circuits (a bit more pipe, and valves or pumps, and another thermostat) will solve the problem you describe reliably and with less disruption to the house, and for less cost, by isolating the bedroom heat to a circuit controlled by a thermostat in the bedroom.

If you do have a desire to try radiant wall, you will still want to separate the heating loops, and the radiant wall loop should probably also have a control to reduce the temperature in that loop (it's a common item - "injection circulator" is one term, there are also valves to achieve the same end) basically the fluid in the wall is running around a loop that is connected to the loop from the heat source, but only enough hot fluid from the heat source is added to the loop to maintain the lower temperature suitable for the radiant loop, rather than running the full flow of high-temperature fluid through the radiant loop.